# SQL Server on Linux "Verify that the certificate file(s) are of a supported format."

Tags: linux, sql-server

I'm running SQL Server on Linux (CentOS 8)
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU19) (KB4535007) - 14.0.3281.6 (X64)

I'm trying to setup TLS certificates for incoming connections and followed [these command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-encrypted-connections?view=sql-server-ver16)s

```
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlscert (path to pem file)
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlskey (path to key file)
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tlsprotocols 1.2
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.forceencryption 1
```

However when the server starts, it crashes after a few seconds with the following error:

```
2022-07-13 15:37:28.85 spid19s     Error: 49941, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2022-07-13 15:37:28.85 spid19s     Unable to load one or more of the user-specified certificate file(s). Verify that the certificate file(s) are of a supported format.
2022-07-13 15:37:28.89 spid19s     Error: 49939, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2022-07-13 15:37:28.89 spid19s     Unable to initialize user-specified certificate configuration. The server is being shut down. Verify that the certificate is correctly configured. Error[30]. State[51].
```

The certificates themselves where created using openssl. I have a self-signed CA that I used to sign all my certificates. These have worked without issue in other applications (e.g NGINX / Tomcat)

I've verified the certificate subject and SAN entries are all accurate.

The error is very ambiguous. I'm not sure what is meant by "supported format" and there is nothing on Microsofts sites to suggest what this is. They themselves give examples using PEM format certificates.

Comment: Can you clarify `(path to pem file)`. Is this include the name of `PEM` file itself? and do mssql have rights to read the files?

Comment: Yes thats right and I followed the Microsoft advice to change permissions to 400, ownership is by mssql.